# Debugging Hive in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to modify Hive and hence am trying to debug it in Eclipse. I followed the instruction in the wiki to setup Hive in Eclipse (https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/gettingstarted-eclipsesetup.html).

When I try to launch the CLI using HiveCLI.launch template, it shows be the Hive CLI, but any query that I execute results in an error "ERROR metastore.HiveMetaStore: JDO datastore error".

The interesting part is that if I just launch hive in terminal using "/hive/build/dist/bin/hive", then everything works perfect. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? If you can point me to any document which shows how to debug hive would be of tremendous use!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try out these steps:

1. Start the thrift server by opening CLI usind command :
   `hive --service hiveserver 10000`
2. Now you can run your program from eclipse .

Note: 10000 is the port number generally.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Copy your code as a jar file to your cluster

Step 2: RUN THE FOLLOWING COMMAND ON CLUSTER
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777

Step 3: Go to your ecllipse code. Right Click -> Debug as -> Debug Configuration 
Put the follwing parameters :
Host name: COMPLETE ADDRESS OF YOUR CLUSTER
Port : 7777
Project Name: Choose the project in ecllipse which has the code class
DEBUG !

Step 4:
Run the code from the dev cluster by the usual command of spark-submit

You can see your code running in Dev cluster, but coming to a halt and passing the pointer back to ecllipse when it tries to execute the Debug break point.

Step 5:
To go back to the original non suspending mode:
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n

---